# Rsyslog not logging Windows Events

Tags: linux, windows, syslog, windows-event-log, rsyslog

I am trying to configure sending Windows Events to rsyslog server, but rsyslog ignores them.

```
$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off

template(name="OnlyMsg" type="string" string="%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n")

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="10514" ruleset="Remote10514LogProcess")

template(name="RemoteWinLogSavePath" type="list") {
    constant(value="/var/spool/rsyslog/windows-pci-dss/")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="year")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="month")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="day")
    constant(value="/")
    property(name="$.logpath" )
}

ruleset(name="Remote10514LogProcess") {
    set $.logpath = replace($programname, "-", "/");
    if ( $syslogtag contains "Security" ) then 
        action(type="omfile" dynaFileCacheSize="1024"
               dynaFile="RemoteWinLogSavePath" 
               template="OnlyMsg" flushOnTXEnd="off" asyncWriting="on" 
               flushInterval="1" ioBufferSize="64k")
}
```

fragment of a packet received from windows server

```
14:28:31.034046 IP 192.168.1.2.64733 > 192.168.1.49.10514: UDP, length 286
        0x0000:  4500 013a 7eb8 0000 8011 231e c0a8 0b5b  E..:~.....#....[
        0x0010:  c0a8 0b31 fcdd 2912 0126 e9cd 3c31 3837  ...1..)..&..<187
        0x0020:  3e4e 6f76 2020 3120 3134 3a32 383a 3330  >Nov..1.14:28:30
        0x0030:  2050 524f 442d 3031 2d44 4330 3320 5365  .WIN-SERVER.Se
        0x0040:  6375 7269 7479 2d41 7564 6974 696e 673a  curity-Auditing:
        0x0050:  2034 3737 363a 2041 5544 4954 5f46 4149  .4776:.AUDIT_FAI
        0x0060:  4c55 5245 2054 6865 2063 6f6d 7075 7465  LURE.The.compute
        0x0070:  7220 6174 7465 6d70 7465 6420 746f 2076  r.attempted.to.v
...
```

Even if I just specify

```
:syslogtag, startswith, "Security-Auditing:" -/var/spool/rsyslog/Security/Auditing.txt
:syslogtag, startswith, "Security-Auditing:" ~
```

will not work.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, Windows cannot forward event logs "like that" to a
>   remote SYSLOG server. Instead, you should consider one of the
>   following approaches:

- **Setup a Windows Event Collector (WEC) server** and configure your source clients (WEF) to target this collector. Then you have to install on top of it an agent solution that will forward your logs to your final target (eg: a SIEM). Main available agent solution are: *NXLog agent CE, WinLogBeat, RSYSLOG, Splunk Agent UF, ...*
- **Use an agentless approach with an emulated WEC server**. This can be done with two solutions on the market: NXLog agent Enterprise or SYSLOG-NG Premium.
- **Deploy one of the agent solutions mentioned** previously on all your Windows source clients. But depending on the size of your environment, this can be very complicated. I would personally suggest the WEC approach instead.

Note that if your source hosts are in the same domain, WEC with Kerberos authentication can be setup very quickly. In case your source hosts are in Workgroup, you may need to deploy and use TLS certificates.

In all cases, and if you want to get more familiar with Windows Event Collector capacities, I can recommend to have a look on this [presentation](https://www.radarservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Swiss-Cyber-Storm_WindowsChallenge_EN.pdf).

Comment: I’m sorry, I forgot to say that the utility https://code.google.com/archive/p/eventlog-to-syslog/ is used to send logs